# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in line

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I need help, this is the code where i get a syntax error. thx guys

```
            <?
                if ($_POST['provincia']){
                echo "<option value="$_POST[pronvicia]" selected="selected">$_POST[provincia]</option>";}

                else{
                echo "<option value="" selected="selected">seleziona</option>";};
            ?>
```

Comment: What is the error message? Please add the message by **editing your post**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge your string with `.` and use `'` when needed

```
 <?php
                if ($_POST['provincia']){
                echo "<option value=".$_POST['pronvicia']."  selected='selected'>".$_POST['provincia']."</option>";}

                else{
                echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>seleziona</option>";}
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
echo "<option value='$_POST[pronvicia]' selected='selected'>$_POST[provincia]</option>";}
```

Or:

```
echo "<option value=\"$_POST[pronvicia]\" selected=\"selected\">$_POST[provincia]</option>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

code should look like this

```
 <?
            if ($_POST['provincia']){
            echo "<option value=".$_POST[pronvicia]." selected='selected'>".$_POST[provincia]."</option>";}

            else{
            echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>seleziona</option>";};
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
                   if ($_POST['provincia']){
        echo '<option value="'.$_POST['pronvicia'].'" selected="selected">'.$_POST['provincia'].'</option>';
    }
else{
        echo '<option value="" selected="selected">seleziona</option>';
    }
            ?>
```